# Flying between Tanzania and Madagascar

Tags: air-travel, africa, tanzania, madagascar

We are planning a one-month trip to Rwanda, Tanzania and Madagascar, but looking at the flights it seems that you can not fly directly from e.g. Dar es-Salaam to anywhere in Madagascar.

Does anyone have any updated info?

Answer (score 3):

According to my searches, Ethiopian Airlines flies that route, but with a connection in Addis Ababa.

It looks like Antananarivo has direct flights to Johannesburg, Addis Ababa, and Nairobi as well as some island airports in the area, as well as Guangzhou, China and Paris.

So... it appears like a connection in Addis Ababa will be your best bet.